# CQ5 / AEM Change permissions on groups with curl

Tags: curl, aem

I need to construct a curl command that will change read etc permissions for groups on specific nodes in the repository. I can obviously do this manually, but need to create a script. I have seen examples that do this for users, but I can't make it work for groups. In my examples below, "acme-authors" is a group.

Produces apparently correct response, but does not change anything

```
curl -u admin:admin -F:applyTo=acme-authors \
    http://server.com:4502/etc/tags/acme.acl.json
```

Gives "no principalId found" error

```
curl -u admin:admin -FprincipalId=acme-authors -Fprivilege@jcr:read=denied \
    http://server.com:4502/etc/tags/acme.acl.json

curl -u admin:admin -FgroupId=acme-authors -Fprivilege@jcr:read=denied \
    http://server.com:4502/etc/tags/acme.acl.json
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this for groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full documentation of the RESTful ACL service can be found on the [Sling website](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/managing-permissions-jackrabbit-accessmanager.html).

In following examples I'll use Geometrixx tags and groups, so they may be tested on a clean AEM 5.6. BTW: my instance didn't have the *jackrabbit-accessmanager* bundle and I had to install it manually from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.accessmanager).

**Reading ACL**

In order to read the current ACL, send a GET request with `acl` selector:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/etc/tags/marketing.acl.json
```

You may also list effective (inherited) ACL using `eacl` selector:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/etc/tags/marketing.eacl.json
```

**Setting permission**

Send POST request with `modifyAce` selector and `principalId` parameter:

```
curl -u admin:admin -FprincipalId=content-authors -Fprivilege@jcr:read=denied \
    http://localhost:4502/etc/tags/marketing.modifyAce.json
```

**Removing permission**

Send POST request with `deleteAce` selector and `:applyTo` parameter:

```
curl -u admin:admin -F:applyTo=content-authors \
    http://localhost:4502/etc/tags/marketing.deleteAce.json
```

Comment: Thanks Tomek, that works for me. Let me be the first to upvote your answer!

Comment: Note that this requires jackrabbit-accessmanager to be installed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587635/how-to-give-user-permissions-programatically