# How to give user permissions programmatically?

Tags: xml, permissions, aem

I know I can give permissions in

```
${host}:4502/useradmin
```

when I double click user login and go to `Permissions` tab

I want to give permissions when I deploy content package.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added under the folder where I want to configure permissions file with name

```
_rep_policy.xml
```

with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:rep="internal"
          jcr:primaryType="rep:ACL">
    <allow
            jcr:primaryType="rep:GrantACE"
            rep:principalName="myusername"
            rep:privileges="{Name}[jcr:read,rep:write,jcr:versionManagement,jcr:lockManagement]"/>
</jcr:root>
```

and in pom.xml I added following entry:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallContentPackage</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-package</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            ...
                            <properties>
                                <acHandling>Overwrite</acHandling>   //allow modify permissions
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        ....
```

Answer (score 5):

When you give permission for a user for a particular node/path , it basically stores the permission on the node level below the rep:policy node (allow/deny).

> I want to give permissions when I deploy content package.

- You can deploy an AEM package containing only rep:policies which will serve the same purpose of setting up permissions through useradmin.

You can refer to [ACL packager from ACS Tools](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/acl-packager.html) for packaging ACLs.

*Note : The user who is installing the package needs to have permission to set ACLs*

To programmatically set ACLs (as the title of your question says), 
you might care to check out few Jackrabbit/JCR interfaces/classes .

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.JackrabbitAccessControlManager
org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.JackrabbitAccessControlList
javax.jcr.security.Privilege
```

Comment: Indeed you might want to look into session.getAccessControlManager().getPolicies(...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use curl command to set permissions. AEM OOB provide Curl scripts to:
1. Create/Delete groups
2. Create/Delete users
3. Add groups/users in groups
4. Add permissions in group

one example of assigning permissions using curl is:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST --noproxy localhost -FauthorizableId=MyGroup -Fchangelog=path:/content/site/page/path,read:true,modify:true,create:true,delete:true,acl_read:false,acl_edit:false,replicate:false http://localhost:4502/.cqactions.html
```

This can be automated using a script easily (bat file or a shell script or some java program).

Comment: Great answer and I'd like to highlight the AEM OOB part. All the privilege@jcr:read examples around require the jackrabbit-accessmanager bundle.